# infragistics webdatagrid inserting a row with hidden columns

Tags: javascript, asp.net, grid

I am using an Infragistics data grid V11.2.  The grid only displays 1 column with 10 columns hidden.  I need to insert a row into the grid. The RowAdding element does not support Templates. So when I use this option it displays only 1 column.  I tried creating a table above the grid with the fields to add and a button to add that calls a javascript function.  When I have it in debug, the function is not called after clicking the button. Also, I don't know now this function can trigger the stored procedure to insert the data into the database.

This is the table I created to add a row:

```
<table style="width: 875px; background-color:#F0F8FF; text-align:left;">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="left" class="style1">
        <b>Add New Office:</b>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Address Prefix:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressPrefix" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
    <td>
        Address:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Address Suffix:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressSuffix" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
    <td>
        City:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        City Mailing:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCityMailing" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
    <td>
        State:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Zip:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </td>
    <td>
        County ID:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCounty" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="Name" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Lat:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLat" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender3" runat="server" MaskType="Number"
            TargetControlID="txtLat" Mask="99\.999999999" AcceptNegative="Left">
        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
    </td>
    <td>
        Long:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLong" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender4" runat="server" MaskType="Number"
            TargetControlID="txtLong" Mask="99\.999999999" AcceptNegative="Left">
        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="left">  
         <input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="Add New Row" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the infragistics grid and the datasource:

```
    <ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid runat="server" height="600px" width="875px" ClientIDMode="Static" 
        AutoGenerateBands="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyFields="ID"          
        DataMember="SqlDataSource1_DefaultView" StyleSetName="Windows7" ID="wdgOffice"
        DataSourceID="WebHierarchicalDataSource1" Key="SqlDataSource1_DefaultView" 
        onrowadded="wdgOffice_RowAdded" onrowadding="wdgOffice_RowAdding">
        <Columns>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="ID" Key="ID" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="ID" />
                <header text="ID" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="AddressPrefix" Key="AddressPrefix" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="AddressPrefix" />
                <header text="AddressPrefix" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Address" Key="Address" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="Address" />
                <header text="Address" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="AddressSuffix" Key="AddressSuffix" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="AddressSuffix" />
                <header text="AddressSuffix" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="City" Key="City" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="City" />
                <header text="City" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="CityMailing" Key="CityMailing" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="CityMailing" />
                <header text="CityMailing" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="State" Key="State" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="State" />
                <header text="State" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Zip" Key="Zip" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="Zip" />
                <header text="Zip" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="CountyName" Key="CountyID" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="CountyID" />
                <header text="CountyID" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Lat" Key="Lat" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="Lat" />
                <header text="Lat" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>            
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Long" Key="Long" Hidden="true">
                <Header Text="Long" />
                <header text="Long" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>
            <ig:BoundDataField DataFieldName="Name" Key="Name" Width="95%">
                <Header Text="Name" />
                <header text="Name" />
            </ig:BoundDataField>    
        </Columns>   
    </ig:WebHierarchicalDataGrid>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<ig:WebHierarchicalDataSource ID="WebHierarchicalDataSource1" runat="server">
    <DataViews>
        <ig:DataView ID="SqlDataSource1_DefaultView" DataMember="DefaultView" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" />           
    </DataViews>       
</ig:WebHierarchicalDataSource>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CAP06 %>" 
    SelectCommand="phyadmGetOffices2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"     
    InsertCommand="phyadmInsOffices" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">              
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="AddressPrefix" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />      
        <asp:Parameter Name="AddressSuffix" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CityMailing" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="State" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Zip" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="CountyID" ControlID="ddlCounty" Type="Int32" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Lat" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Long" Type="Decimal" />    
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CAP06 %>"
    SelectCommand="phyadmGetCounty2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have also tried using the RowAdding behavior by adding:

```
<ig:RowAdding>
    <AddNewRowClientEvents EnteringEditMode="WebDataGrid1_RowAdding_EnteringEditMode" />
</ig:RowAdding>
```

This did not work either. It added an insertion row. (blank row with a +). When the user clicked the blank row, the method WebDataGrid1_RowAdding_EnteringEditMode was called.  But I need to add 10 fields to the row. THis was not intuitive.

If anyone has any other approaches to how I can insert a row into the database and update the grid, I would greatly appreciate it.

THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem...you cannot insert a hidden row into an Infragistics Grid.  What I did was create a table above the grid with an 'Add' button to insert row data with hidden elements.